# floating damage text in 3D

Tags: 3d, sprites, gui, combat, godot-3

followed this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlvBqz8bhCo

the guy is working mostly in 2D, i tried to apply the same method but I'm hating working with UI in godot, everytime I seem to get something right, I get 100 more wrong.

the problem I'm having is that when I hit multiple enemies, only one damage indicator shows
[image]

so basically in the code the func _ready() animates the damage indicator making it shrinks after it appears... and the self.queue_free() deletes the damage after the animation is complete

I'm using a third person controller with a crossair, the damage shows offset to the left of the crossair, which is perfect for now... but no matter how many enemies I hit... only one damage pop up shows... even when enemies have different ammounts of defense so it should show diferent damage texts... it only ever shows the damage of the first enemy hit

[image]

the floating damage is called by the enemy when it is hit
[image]

there is the full enemy.gd code https://github.com/Ceisri/Godot-Action-Combat/blob/main/Creatures/Enemies/Enemy.gd

The player calls the function that damages the enemies with :

```
func attack():
var enemies = hitbox.get_overlapping_bodies()
for enemy in enemies:
    if enemy.has_method("onhit"):
        #enemy.hurt()
        enemy.onhit(damage)
```

which is the mirrored version of the Enemy script...
, it also has the function to be damaged:

```
func onhit(damage):
$GUI/HealthBar.value = int((health / maxhealth) * 100)
health -= (damage - defense)
staggered = true
```

it basically gets the (damage) from the enemy and the (defense) from the player... the opposite happens when the enemy is being hit.

so aggressor damage - victim defense = damage caused to victim

Comment: And you create them how on hit? In addition you should use the code markup instead of screenshots.

Comment: This is still not the full code since it is missing the part where you define/ preload `floatingtext`. And it is still done as a screenshot and not as text.

Comment: @Zibelas added the github  but it's var floatingtext = preload("res://UI/floatingtext.tscn")

Comment: I have basically zero Godot experience, but even for all that it is worth, you are saying onhit is called by the enemy when it is hit. But nowhere in your enemy script are you calling onhit on the enemy. You are calling it on the player, so when the enemy is hitting your player, not vise versa. Your action combat script has no onhit function as well. So where exactly is `Enemy.onhit(damage)` called?

Comment: @Zibelas I didn't update the player script on github because it only lets me load a small ammount of data.  but I'll add the part where damage interraction happens in the question

Comment: It is important to always have all relevant parts to answer a question. And you should take a look how to set up github for a full project, those text files are so small, loading a single web page is loading more data than all your scripts combined

Comment: @Zibelas sorry ill fix it

Comment: [`damage` & `defense` are set](https://github.com/Ceisri/Godot-Action-Combat/blob/main/Creatures/Enemies/Enemy.gd#L24), but never changed, so I would expect all the labels to display the same amount. If they are changed, it's in some other script, which is a good example of why you should post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to concisely demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Pikalek Enemy2.gd in the screenshot, it is the same script as Enemy.gd but the only difference is that the defense variable is higher for testing...I just right clicked on the first enemy script, and selected dubplicate then edited the defense variable and then created a new goblin to which i assigned Enemy2.gd instead of Enemy.gd... If I attacked the enemy2 alone it showed the new damage, if i attacked more of them at the same time, it always shows the text damage of the first enemy to be hit

Comment: That's the first time you mentioned the Enemy2 script & associated functionality. This is why complete, self contained questions are the norm for GDSE.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, before no matter how many enemies you hit, the first floating damage would ovveride all the others thus only the first will show.

now it shows all damage every time someone is hit.

Solution:

-Get the screen size, divide by two to get the center

-Spawn the text at the center

But now it still overlaps

-Create an offset

-Spawn the text offset to the cursor with a random range of positions.

```
var offset = Vector2(rand_range(-20, 20), rand_range(-20, 20))
return center + offset
```

to use them in your game, just follow the tutorial and then add my part of code...

full script at :
https://github.com/Ceisri/Godot-Action-Combat/blob/main/scripts/floatingtext.gd

now it can display as many damage indicators as possible, and all around the cursor, regardless of monitor size.
[image]